# Navegar con teclado un menú HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer hacer para poder navegar con las flechas de arriba y abajo del teclado a través de un menú en html. Gracias por la ayuda.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Hola gracias por la sugerencia, pero es que se como hacerlo solo con el mouse pero lo que no se es como navegar con el teclado a través de ese menú. me gustaría obtener una idea de como hacerlo. por eso en el momento no tengo código para moverme por el menú con el teclado solo tengo código del menu.

Comment: Puedes empezar por poner el código HTML de tu menú para poder ver la estructura.

Comment: Listo, ese menú es el que quiero recorrer con el teclado. haber si me dan una idea de como hacerlo... les agradecería.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo que he hecho con jQuery. Creo que es lo que quieres. He puesto comentarios con la explicación pero si tienes cualquier duda, me dices.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    //Keydown
    //Buscamos los links con clase active
    var active = $('.menu').find("a.active");
    var storeTarget;
    if (active.length != 0) {
      //Si existe alguno, borramos la clase y seleccionamos el siguiente link (vamos hacia abajo)
      active.removeClass("active");
      storeTarget = active.parent().next();
    } else {
      //Si no existe, seleccionamos el primer elemento
      storeTarget = $('.menu').first("li");
    }
    //Le asignamos la clase active
    storeTarget.children().addClass("active");
  } else if (e.which == 38) {
    //Key up. Lo mismo pero empezando desde abajo
    var active = $('.menu').find("a.active");
    var storeTarget;
    if (active.length != 0) {
      active.removeClass("active");
      storeTarget = active.parent().prev();
    } else {
      storeTarget = $('.menu').last("li");
    }
    storeTarget.children().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<!-- librería jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>

<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si eso era lo que buscaba, Millones  de gracias !!!